# Add COM library to UWP

Tags: c#, com, uwp, windows-10-universal

I built a C# project where I added a COM library as I reference & could make calls to that library without any issues.

I'm trying to do the same but in a Universal Windows Platform (UWP) project but when I try to build the project I get this error:

```
"Please make sure your COM object is in the allowed list of CoCreateInstanceFromApp"
```

Is there anyway I could add the COM library as a reference to my UWP project and call it as I did in the standard C# project ?

Thanks

Comment: uwp has a lot of limitations. which com library are you adding?

Comment: @DanielA.White It's 3rd party C COM library.  I have no access to code behind it.  Thanks